# UWP: Failed to set access rights to AppX

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, template10

UWP + Template10 + VS2015 continues to have basic development issues.

Debugging this [Minimal Template 10 UWP app (git repo)](https://bitbucket.org/rchfreytag/csvtoqbsiifconverter/overview) gives the following error:

> Error     DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070005:
>   Failed to set access rights to AppX. (0x80070005) CSVtoQBsIIFConverter

All I did was add a README.txt and try to debug.  It builds just fine but fails to deploy with the above error message.

Environment:

- Windows 10 Pro, Version 1607, OS Build 14393.1198
- VS 2015 Pro, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Template 10 (installed from Nuget), Version 1.1.12.

I have tried:

- altering the Package.appmanifest->Capabilities to allow all
  permissions.
- running VS2015 as Administrator.
- searching here and the Internet for answers.

*Your suggestions are very welcome!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your dev machine or intended device setup for receiving the application from Visual Studio.  I have a feeling it isn't, follow the instructions on this link for setting up your environment for sideloading from visual studio or mobile devices for developer more or as per instructions.

Also keep in mind this isn't a Template10 issue more of a Windows 10 configuration for app development one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

Comment: Turns out that VS2017 was deploying the debugged project by default (from when VS was being started) to an architecture other than that of the development machine (and one I had never selected)!  This peculiar error message completely vanished with I noticed that the debugger was trying to deploy the project to the wrong architecture.